# Docker error after copying a file called `run`

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM artprod.dev.bloomberg.com/auto/ubuntu:16.04

COPY run .
```

Building works okay, but then when I run it, I get this error that goes something like this:

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:364: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting
```

If I don't copy the `run` file or rename it to something else, it works fine.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the image root directory, there is a folder called `run` which contains a file which is mounted by Docker.  Running the `COPY` command overwrites the directory, unlike the `cp` bash command, resulting in destruction of the file, causing the error.  Perhaps it is a bad idea to copy files into the root of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You are overiding `run` directory of the container, renamed it to something else then it should work like `copy my_run .`

> Apparently, many tools (among them udev) will soon require a /run/
>   directory that is mounted early (as tmpfs). Arch developers introduced
>   /run last month to prepare for this.
>
> The udev runtime data moved from /dev/.udev/ to /run/udev/. The /run
>   mountpoint is supposed to be a tmpfs mounted during early boot,
>   available and writable to for all tools at any time during bootup, it
>   replaces /var/run/, which should become a symlink someday.

[what-is-this-new-run-filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem)

ubuntu Container expect these files in the run directory in case of ubuntu

```
initctl  lock  log  mount  sendsigs.omit.d  shm  systemd  user  utmp
```

> Perhaps it is a bad idea to copy files into the root of the image.

The idea may be bad but the actual reason is above.

in container common way to copy the file to `/app`

```
copy run /app
```